# java- how to pass multiple integer/string values as single object to function-and reconstruct values from the object

Tags: java, function, parameters

In a java app, I have to first pass multiple integer/string values packaged as a single object parameter to a target function, and then the target function has to correctly re-construct the integer/string values from the object that has been passed to it as an input parameter.

What is the best/recommended way for doing this?

The target function will be invoked from another java function only(in a separate program)...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class for packing all the parameters. In this case, the class acts as a transfer object for the parameters. For example, instead of doing this:

```
void myMethod(int param1, String param2, boolean param3)
```

Do this:

```
void myMethod(ParamTO param)
```

And define a transfer object like this:

```
public class ParamTO {
    private int param1;
    private String param2;
    private boolean param3;
    // get/set methods for the attributes
}
```

The way to "correctly re-construct the integer/string values from the object" is by simply calling the get/set methods corresponding to each attribute. If you don't know beforehand the attributes that need to be retrieved, you can use reflection for obtaining the attribute's values.

Alternatively, you could pass a `Map` with the parameters, where the key is the parameter's name and the value the parameter's value. Of course, you'll have to cast the parameters to the appropriate type, or use reflection:

```
void myMethod(Map<String, Object> params)
```